# Document AI unsupported input file format

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

Since the last update with Document AI Node.js API, I'm not able to send in JPEG file formats any more. I received the following message first:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: At this time, the only MIME types supported are 'application/pdf','application/json', 'image/gif' and 'image/tiff'.
```

When I changed my code to handle TIFF images I got the following message:

> (node:15782) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unsupported input file format.

I'm sure the file is a TIFF, I store it in cloud storage first and the content type is described as "image/tiff"

I attached some images for clarification.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you think you could provide an example of tiff file for reproduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Document AI API has been updated in the time since this post was originally made. I recommend using the [`v1` REST API](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors/process) and [Node.JS Client Libraries](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/documentai/latest/index.html)

The [Supported Files](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/file-types) page in the documentation also lists the supported File Types with the appropriate MimeTypes.

Answer (score 0):

I have ever had a similar problem to you with PDF file.
I uploaded pdf files to google cloud storage and was going to run document AI NodeJS API with the files, but I got the same error as you.
"(node:15782) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unsupported input file format."
In my code, the mimeType was set into 'application/pdf'.
But the problem was fixed after the mimeType was set into 'PDF'.
I wonder if this helps you even a little bit.